# androidx.startup.InitializationProvider in your AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest, androidx, android-12

I am updating my android Nugets to latest version. I have been testing after updating each package. In the below order, after updating google.android.material , I got the below error.

**Xamarin.AndroidX.Appcompat  to 1.4.2.1 version.

Xamarin.Google.Android.Material to 1.6.1.1 version.**
It did installed its dependent packages as well.

There are no build errors.
But when I deploy it to device, app is crashing with below exception.

***Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ProcessLifecycleInitializer cannot be initialized lazily.
Please ensure that you have:***

```
<meta-data
    android:name='androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer' 
    android:value='androidx.startup' />
```

***under InitializationProvider in your AndroidManifest.xml'***

After adding below piece of code, the app did deployed.

```
<provider android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup" tools:node="merge">
      <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup" />
</provider>
```

But I am not sure what is the use of it and why my app need to have it ?
Is this the right way to add this piece of code ?
Is there any disadvantages of adding this ?

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should have been generated automatically by the build process. Check the generated manifest (merged manifest) in the debug/release obj folder.

Does it not generate it if you rebuild again if you exclude what you manually added?

If it persists report it at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues

Comment: **What is the use of it being in obj folder ?** I excluded my piece of code and cleaned my project , then rebuild the project. The debug/mergemanifest does has this provider.  Still my app is throwing the above exception while deploying.

Comment: If that is the case, then as I said earlier report it at the above link